# : File has already been moved - cannot be transferred again in spring mvc while upload image

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I read many solution on google and also on this site for this problem but nothing helpfull.
i am trying to upload image in spring mvc project dir **\webapp\assets\images** and also to server by using **randomUUID** and get the above  error.
pls someone help me

Here is my bean

```
@Entity
@Table(name="documentsww")
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    public Document(){

        this.code="DOC"+UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(26).toUpperCase();
        this.code="DOC"+UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(26).toUpperCase();

    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }


    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }


    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
     @Column
    private String code;
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name="content")
    @Transient
    private MultipartFile  file;


    public MultipartFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    }
```

and Controller is

```
@Controller
public class ImageCoontroller {

    @Autowired
    DocumentDao documentDao;
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String getpage() {



        return "register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/it")
    public String save(
            @ModelAttribute("document") Document document,HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("the values are  Description is  Code is ");
  documentDao.save(document);
    if(!document.getFile().getOriginalFilename().equals("")){
        ImageUtill.uploadfile(request,document.getFile(),document.getCode());

    }


        return "register";
    }

}
```

the imageUtill class

```
public class ImageUtill {

    private static final String ABS_PATH="C:\\Users\\Junaid\\Documents\\workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE\\Uplaod\\src\\main\\webapp\\assets\\images";
    private static String REAL_PATH="";
    public static void uploadfile(HttpServletRequest request, MultipartFile file, String code) {
    Logger loger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImageUtill.class);
        REAL_PATH=request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/assets/images/");
        loger.info(ABS_PATH);
        loger.info(REAL_PATH);
        System.out.println(REAL_PATH);
        System.out.println(ABS_PATH);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(!new File(ABS_PATH).exists()){
            new File(ABS_PATH).mkdirs();


        }
        if(!new File(REAL_PATH).exists()){
            new File(REAL_PATH).mkdirs();
        //  F:\SpringProjects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Image\WEB-INF\images
            //F:\SpringProjects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Image\WEB_INF\images

        }
        try {
        //

            file.transferTo(new File(REAL_PATH+code+".jpg"));
            file.transferTo(new File(ABS_PATH+code+".jpg"));
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use MultipartFile#transferTo method twice, second call of transferTo method should be replaced with a logic of file copying. You can use [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) to copy files.

Almost pseudocode:

```
String firstFilePath = REAL_PATH+code+".jpg";
String secondFilePath = ABS_PATH+code+".jpg";
file.transferTo(new File(firstFilePath));
Files.copy(Paths.get(firstFilePath), Paths.get(secondFilePath));
```

Comment: yessss you solve my problem thank you very muchhhhhhhhhh